# How to check for a different element in a list in C#?

Tags: c#, list

I have a list (`List<string>`), let's call it `foolist` which will have the following four items, describing status:
`"InProgress"`, `"Queued"`, `"Fail"`, `"Success"` and `"UpToDate"`.

How could I check if all the elements on my list are of one of those types? If `"InProgress"`, `"Queued"`, `"Fail"` are any element of my list, then I would like to return the same element. To do so I am just using the following:

`if (foolist.Contains("InProgress")) {}`

And I am doing so with all the three elements. What I would like is to check if all the items in my list are the same. Which is the most efficient way to do it?

Also, I would like to check if my `foolist` just contains items of the type `Success` and `UpToDate`.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How could I check if all the elements on my list are of one of those
>   types?

You can check if all the status are the same via `All`:

```
foolist.All(x => x == "InProgress");
```

and you can check if any via `Any`:

```
foolist.Any(x => x == "InProgress");
```

you could even combine the conditions if needed:

```
foolist.Any(x => x == "InProgress" || x == "Success");
```

and so forth...

> Also, I would like to check if my foolist just contains items of the
>   type Success and UpToDate.

in which case `foolist.All(item => item == "Success" || items == "UpToDate")` should suffice.

Comment: @Marisa yes you need `System.Linq` for this. note that you don't have to use Linq but it's one of several ways you can do it. you could do it using an imperative loop if needed.

Comment: downvoters can I know what part of my answer is not useful to improve my answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [All](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Let say available types are in List Types , validFooList and invalidFooList

```
        List<string> types = new List<string>
        {
            "InProgress", "Queued", "Fail", "Success" , "UpToDate"
        };

        List<string> validFooList = new List<string>
        {
            "InProgress", "Queued", "Fail", "Success" , "UpToDate"
        };


        List<string> invalidFooList= new List<string>
        {
            "InProgress", "Queued", "Fail", "Success" , "UpToDate","dump"
        };
```

now use All to determine whether all the elements in a sequence satisfy a condition

```
        bool f = validFooList.All(f => types.Contains(f));// return true

        bool t = invalidFooList.All(f => types.Contains(f)); //return false
```